# how to verify sapguitree("").activeitem is available in sapguitree using uft

Tags: hp-uft

I would like to know if i can able to identify activeitem(below code) is available in SapGuiTree in SAP.

code:

SAPGuiSession("guicomponenttype:=12").SAPGuiWindow("guicomponenttype:=21").SAPGuiTree("treetype:=SapColumnTree").ActivateItem "Inbound Monitor;11.05.2016;1111;Sales Movement","Sales Movement"

i tried below method but not worked

if isNull 'code' then
else
statement
end if

Can anyone suggest any method to identy this issue

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by checking all the node values under a `SAPGuiTree` object.

```
'Set Object
Set TreeObj = SAPGuiSession("a").SAPGuiWindow("b").SAPGuiTree("c").Object
'First you need to get all values under this tree
Set AllValues = TreeObj.GetAllNodeKeys
'Get count
Count = AllValues.Count
'Begin search the value you want
Found = 0
For i = 0 to Count-1
    NodeText = TreeObj.GetNodeTextByKey(AllValues(i))
    If NodeText = "SearchValue" Then
        Found = 1
        Exit For
    End if
Next
If Found = 1 Then
    'Do something
End if
```

Update1:
You can also use Regular Expression to do a pattern match when searching your desired value under a `tree` object.